# this trigger is having error while executing .dynamic query doesnt work here .It has been converted from oracle

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
  The code for contanation is not workinghere
```

Thanks for the reply it looks like lot of syntaxes needs to be changed

the trigger in mysql is different tahn oracle in terms of syntaxes

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems immediately.

1. Use of `||` for string concatenation. By default in MySQL, the `||` operator is a logic `OR` operator, not string concatenation. Use the [CONCAT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for string concatenation. If you [set the SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`, then you can use `||` for string concatenation, but this is not enabled by default.
2. `open cursor for <stmt>` is not supported on MySQL. The support for cursors in MySQL is quite different from Oracle. You can't just port Oracle PL/SQL procedures to MySQL, you basically have to develop new procedures. You really need to study the [documentation and examples on cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html).
3. It seems like you want to build a dynamic SQL query inside the trigger, and execute it. MySQL does not support dynamic SQL inside a trigger or a function, only in a procedure.
4. You can't run a cursor for a dynamic SQL statement in any kind of stored routine — trigger, procedure, or function. The SQL statement must be declared, which means the syntax must be fixed.

   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html says:

   > SQL syntax for prepared statements can be used within stored procedures, but not in stored functions or triggers. However, a cursor cannot be used for a dynamic statement that is prepared and executed with PREPARE and EXECUTE. The statement for a cursor is checked at cursor creation time, so the statement cannot be dynamic.

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but what you're trying to do just isn't possible in a trigger or a stored procedure.

I not going to spend time to figure out what your trigger is intended to do, so I can't recommend an alternative way of doing it. I'm just letting you know that triggers and stored procedures in MySQL are entirely different from what you're expecting, and probably you are going to be quite frustrated with the limitations.